# How come 星 (star) is used in 星期 (week)?

Tags: characters, etymology

How come that the character 星 (star) is used in the word for week 星期?

期 means a period of time, but why is week "star"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did China opt for 星期 over 曜日?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/15977/why-did-china-opt-for-%e6%98%9f%e6%9c%9f-over-%e6%9b%9c%e6%97%a5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ancient China, makers of calendars tried to relate rotation of stars or star constellations with mythological deities. In fact, **Chinese calendar doesn't carry the concept of `week`.**

European names for "week days" are represented by Greek/Roman mythological deities. European creating the "week" concept from there.

Chinese scholar use 星期 to represent `week` when China adapt the universal international calendar, which means the day/period of the constellation/star deity complete their "duty roster". Only Sunday 星期日/天 follow the Roman/Greek, which may be due to influence of European missionary.

> 1905年，清朝学部的袁嘉谷筹建编译图书局，后任该局首任局长，编写官定各种教材，设立了一个新机构统一规范教科书中的术语，把七日一周制定为中国自己的“星期”。
>
> In 1905, Qing Dynasty education officer Yuan-Jia-Gu establish translation and library division for the education department to standardised technical jargon. This is when Chinese use `星期` to represent the week.

On the other hand, Japanese is using the Roman/Greek deity to represent days, as in Europe. Japan is using 曜 that carry similar meaning as constellation/star.

Note : [Johann Adam Schall von Bell(May 1, 1592 – August 15, 1666)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Adam_Schall_von_Bell) is helping Qing dynasty perfecting the Chinese calendar.  Chinese has stronger cultural interaction with Europe than many can imagine.

---

(update) for those curious about Japan week days

- 星期一：月曜日 Monday, Máni, avatar of moon
- 星期二：火曜日 Tuesday , The god Tiw, identified with Mars
- 星期三：水曜日 Wednesday, Germanic god Woden, avatar of Mercury
- 星期四：木曜日 Thursday, Thor's (Jupiter's) day
- 星期五：金曜日 Friday, goddess Frigg, Roman goddess Venus
- 星期六：土曜日 Saturday, Roman god Saturn
- 星期日：日曜日 Sunday,   Sól, avatar of Sun

Comment: The 七曜 system is attested back from the [4th century AD in China](http://www.cjvlang.com/Dow/dowjpn.html). Also, in addition to Japanese, the Korean language also preserves the 七曜 system.

Comment: @Michaelyus  Korea once upon a time colonised by Japan.